# Swift - Cannot specialize a non-generic definition using Result<T, Error>

Tags: swift, swift5

Attempting to use latest Swift 5.0 Result class. made a generic function, which builds.  However calling it does not compile.  Is there a different syntax for this?  XCode doesn't make suggestions here.

```
private func buildTask<T: Decodable>(request:URLRequest, handler: @escaping (Result<T, NetworkError>) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        // logic here....
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let data = data, let decodedResponse = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) {
            handler(.success(decodedResponse))
        } else {
            handler(.failure(.errorParsing))
        }
    }
    return task
}

// calling method, Compile error here about generic
func test() {
    let url:URL = URL(string: "http://google.com")!
    let request:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    let task = buildTask<String>(request: request) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success:
            print("good")
        case .failure:
            print("bad")
        }
    }
}
```

// SOLUTION from below poster.

```
let task = buildTask(request: request) { (result:Result<String, NetworkError>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let success):
                print("success \(success)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("error \(error)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: In your `test()` function shouldn't you be calling `buildTask(...)` instead of `dataTask(...)`?

Comment: Sorry pasted it wrong into stackoverflow.  The method was right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift you cannot specify a generic type using `<T>` when calling. The type of the generic method is inferred from the types you are passing to it. In this case, from the `handler` closure:

```
let task = buildTask(request: request) { (result: Result<String, NetworkError>) in
```

When you specify the type of `result`, the compiler can infer the type of the closure and subsequently also the generic type of the method.